# How to delete pages created in panels?

Tags: nodes

I have some testing content that I played with in panels,  but there is only disable options. They are on accessible on this URL:

```
admin/structure/pages
```

How to delete these?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your user's role has the permission to delete panel pages and or nodes.

When there is no delete button under the clicked triangle, and these are Panel nodes, they might be deleted from the node manager and not from Panels (I used it a long time ago for 2-3 panel-nodes and I don't recall exactly if it's there).

Comment: Yep, was a permissions issue, now why on earth does panels come with permissions disabled for admin to control his own site?....I find this behavior very annoying and it causes issues. Is there a way to have ALL modules set as default permission ON for super admin?